# Is it possible to make CSS classes extend each other?

Tags: html, css

I have some CSS classes as:

```
  .span9 {
    width: 870px;
  }
  .span4 {
    width: 370px;
  }
```

In another custom CSS file I want to make another CSS class .span9? How do I do this?

The reason is because a DOM element uses .span4 and I want to override this but it must be overridden in a custom external CSS file.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Explain what you have tried, that might clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the !important feature to override any settings in another file so in your new file you could do something like this:

```
.span9 {
  width: 800px !important;
}
```

Comment: Not necessary if the rule appears after the first one. In fact, it's a bad idea to use `!important` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, CSS is cascading (style sheet) so simply load the changes after the initial styles and it will work as you want.  If you want to override width just re declare, if you want to add styles simple declare them.

Answer (score 1):

If you have different parent of .span you can do this :

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
   <span class="span9"> Hello world!</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.span9{width:870px;}
#parent .span9{width:100px;}
```

Or in you're HTML directly (but it's not a very good method)

```
<span class="span9" style="width:100px!important;"> Hello world</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use `!important`. This will override other CSS rules that come after it, unless they're also marked as `!important`.

So your second stylesheet could contain something like

```
.span9 {
    width: 1020px !important;
  }
```

and that's what the CSS will default to. You can use this to override inbuilt stylesheets in CMSs etc, without having to mess with their actual stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can override it by concatenation of tag name and class name. For example , this : `div.span4` will override simple `.span4` , have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/5dYHG/1/